# An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, sgen

I'm working with **VS2008** and **VS2010** for different projects simultaneously. Recently I tried to generate the serialization assemblies for the Entities Project and was unable to generate the same via visual studio 2010.  This throws up the below error:

```
An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: X:\Dev\Proj\X.Entities\bin\Debug\X.entities.dll.
```

This is be post build event I have setup for the Entities project

```
"$(FrameworkSDKDir)\Bin\sgen" /nologo /force $(TargetFileName)
copy "$(TargetDir)X.Entities.Serializer.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\X.Site\Bin"
```

**I'm able to generate the Serializer dll from the VS 2010 command line.**
For the VS2008 projects; the lines are working fine. However, the errors are on the VS2010 projects!

Is there a different `FrameworkSDKDir` variable for VS2010? if not, how do I modify it to work with both VS2010 and VS2008 projects?

BTW, I use win 2008 Server 32-bit OS, IIS 7 for the development.

Comment: There are 4 versions of sgen.exe in VS2010.  Combinations of 32-bit vs 64-bit and CLR 2 vs CLR 4.  I'm guessing you are getting the .NET 4 version and trying to load it in a project that targets CLR 2.

Comment: @HansPassant: All the projects are set to 4.0 Framework, hence I don't think it is trying to load CLR 2. Even if it is pointing to, how can I change that?

Comment: First you must identify the problem, then you can think about fixing it.  Use ildasm.exe to verify your assumptions, it shows the expected CLR version in the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sgen that you are pointing to is for CLR 2.0. Ideally it will be located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin.

There is a 4.0 version of sgen under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools" which resolves the issue.

Your post build command should start like this:

```
"$(FrameworkSDKDir)\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sgen"
```